# error 500 internal server al intentar agregar un registro,, api rest c# net core 5

Tags: asp.net-web-api

Este es el código donde veo que posiblemente  podría  estar el error.

**ApplicationUserControler.cs**

```
using API_Axosnet.Models;
 using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
 using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
 using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
 using System;
  using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.Linq;
  using System.Threading.Tasks;
 using System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt;

 using System.Security.Claims;
 using System.Text;
 using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
 using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;

   namespace API_Axosnet.Controllers
   {

   [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class ApplicationUserController : ControllerBase
    {
    private UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;
    private SignInManager<ApplicationUser> _singInManager;
    private readonly ApplicationSettings _appSettings;



    public ApplicationUserController(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager, 
    SignInManager<ApplicationUser> signInManager, IOptions<ApplicationSettings> appSettings)
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
        _singInManager = signInManager;
        _appSettings = appSettings.Value;
    }


    [HttpPost]
    [Route("Register")]
    //POST : /api/ApplicationUser/Register
    public async Task<Object> PostApplicationUser(ApplicationUserModel model)
    {
        model.Role = "Admin";
        var applicationUser = new ApplicationUser()
        {
            UserName = model.UserName,
            Email = model.Email,
            FullName = model.FullName
        };

        try
        {
            var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(applicationUser, model.Password);
            await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(applicationUser, model.Role);
            return Ok(result);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            throw ex;
        }
    }


    [HttpPost]
    [Route("Login")]
    //POST : /api/ApplicationUser/Login
    public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginModel model)
    {
        var user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(model.UserName);
        if (user != null && await _userManager.CheckPasswordAsync(user, model.Password))
        {
            var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
            {
                Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(new Claim[]
                {
                    new Claim("UserID",user.Id.ToString())
                }),
                Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(1),
                SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(new 
          SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_appSettings.JWT_Secret)), 
           SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature)
            };
            var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
            var securityToken = tokenHandler.CreateToken(tokenDescriptor);
            var token = tokenHandler.WriteToken(securityToken);
            return Ok(new { token });
        }
        else
            return BadRequest(new { message = "Username or password is incorrect." });
     }

  }
  }
```

Este es  mi ApplicationUser

```
  using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
   using System;
   using System.Collections.Generic;
   using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
   using System.Linq;
   using System.Threading.Tasks;

 namespace API_Axosnet.Models
   {
  public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
 {
    [Column(TypeName = "nvarchar(150)")]
    public string FullName { get; set; }
  }
 }
```

Este es lo que intento ingresar  mediante postman.

```
 {
  "UserName":"Raquel123",
  "Email":"raquel@gmail.com",
  "Password":"raquel123",
  "FullName":"Raquel Vallarta"
  }
```

Este es es el error 500 que me  muestra .

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 
'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SignInManager`1[API_Axosnet.Models.ApplicationUser]' while 
attempting to activate 'API_Axosnet.Controllers.ApplicationUserController'.
 at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.GetService(IServiceProvider 
  sp, Type type, Type requiredBy, Boolean isDefaultParameterRequired)
   at lambda_method9(Closure , IServiceProvider , Object[] )
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerActivatorProvider.<>c__DisplayClass4_0. 
  <CreateActivator>b__0(ControllerContext controllerContext)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerFactoryProvider.<>c__DisplayClass5_0. 
   <CreateControllerFactory>g__CreateController|0(ControllerContext controllerContext)
     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, 
      Scope& 
    scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
     at 
      Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
     --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker. 
     <InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>g__Awaited|19_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State 
        next, 
    Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker. 
   <InvokeAsync>g__Logged|17_1(ResourceInvoker invoker)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint 
    endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext 
   context)
```